# How specific should tags get? e.g., [3tb-hard-drive] vs [hard-drive]

Tags: discussion, tags

Been doing some tag cleanup recently and noticed this oddity:

[Boot utilities for 3 TB hard drives](https://superuser.com/questions/266346/boot-utilities-for-3-tb-hard-drives)

Now, in this case it almost makes sense since this is very specific to the potential problems that a large hard drive over 2.1 GB poses for booting issues. OTOH, it could get out of control.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

no, we definitely do *not* want [large-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/large-hard-drive). Large according to whom? In what time frame?

There is already [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) and [gpt](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gpt) so that should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [2tb-barrier] tag, since that is what it really is?

Comment: This tag could theoretically have a better name but this is most definitely the exact issue being discussed.

Answer (score -1):

[3tb-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/3tb-hard-drive) seems unnecessarily precise to me, however I could see something like [large-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/large-hard-drive) being valid in its place *if and only if* the large size of the drive is a specific factor in the question.

But, [large-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/large-hard-drive) isn't necessarily the best name for it, so alternative suggestions are welcome.
(I say this because large could be taken to mean the physical dimensions, for example)

Comment: But then large-hard-drive loses its significance as well as its mapping to >2tb once we jump to 128bit computing? I think large-hard-drive is the best option for now.

Comment: if you ask me [tag:hard-drive] is sufficient

Comment: @Sathya, frankly in this case I'm not really sure this question is even worth keeping (it feels list-of), so I agree that any type of "largeHDD" tag is not really useful here anyway. But, I can see a viable question where a hard-drive being too large is he source of a real problem and this then making some sense (although I doubt this'll be a frequent occurrence).

Comment: I agree with Sathya, nobody will ever use or search for these tags...

Comment: Would not a GPT tag be in order here, though?  EDIT: Scratch that, it already has one lol.  I think that tag is sufficient!

Comment: Just go with `hard-drive`.

Comment: I am with Jeff, Sathya, and nkinkle on this one. hard-drive is the way to go.